# Grails - escape double quotes in params

Tags: grails, quotes, double-quotes

I have an array of strings that looks like this when I print it on the webpage with ${projectList}:

```
[foo,bar,foo "bar"]
```

And I have a form with select:

```
<g:select class="form-control sbt-color" name='project' value ='${params.project.encodeAsHTML()}' from='${projectList}'/>
```

If I choose 'foo "bar"' params.project will only get 'foo '. Is there a way of fixing this without changing source data?

**Update:**
The only workaround I've found so far is to use:

```
<g:select class="form-control sbt-color" name='project' value ='${params.project}' from='${projectList*.replaceAll("\"","&quot;"}'/>
```

This gives me params.project as I want, but in select list itself double quotes are replaced by " and it looks bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an appropriate solution, but still I had to movify source.

I use map instead of an array:

```
def projectMap = [:]
for (p in projectList){
    projectMap[p.replaceAll("\"","&quot;")] = p
}
```

and use it in select:

```
<g:select class="form-control sbt-color" name="project" value ="${params.project.encodeAsHTML()}" from="${projectMap.entrySet()}" optionKey="value" optionValue="key"/>
```

Btw, I need `.encodeAsHTML()` here to correct display of last chosen option

Answer (score 2):

After removing the `.encodeAsHTML()` this will work. Try this

```
<g:select class="form-control sbt-color" name='project' value ='${params.project}' from='${projectList}'/>
```

Comment: if there was so simple... Still I get the same problem. I've already tried other encodings like '.encodeAsJSON()' with no effect.